# Unable to find alternative to set content position in Itext7 Java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

In Itext5, for setting position in a table, we typically use the following snippet,

```
public static void writeContentInTable(PdfWriter writer, PdfPTable pTable, int xPos, int yPos) {
   try {
       pTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, xPos, yPos, writer.getDirectContent());
   } catch(Exception e) {
       //Logging Errors
   }
}
```

Now while migrating the code from Itext5 to Itext7, I'm facing the challenges to replicate the same. Could you suggest me to replicate the same? Can we replicate the same with the following classes.

```
com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

Comment: *"Can we replicate the same with the following classes. `Table`, `PdfWriter`"* - no. You don't need the `PdfWriter` but instead a `PdfPage` or the `PdfDocument`.

Comment: ... or a `Document` as @Eugene's answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of [PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#writeSelectedRows-int-int-float-float-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte-) is to write a table at absolute positions.

In IText7 there is completely another way to specify absolute positions for a table via [Table.setFixedPosition](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.1/com/itextpdf/layout/ElementPropertyContainer.html#setFixedPosition-float-float-float-)

> Sets values for an absolute repositioning of the Element. The
> coordinates specified correspond to the bottom-left corner of the
> element and it grows upwards. Also has as a side effect that the
> Element's Property.POSITION is changed to fixed.

Your method can look like this:

```java
    public static void writeContentInTable(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Table table, int xPos, int yPos) {
        try {
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
                table.setFixedPosition(xPos, yPos, table.getWidth());
                document.add(table);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //Logging Errors
        }
    }
```

Example to write a table to a certain position:

```java
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void pdfTableTest() throws IOException {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("D:\\test.pdf");
        Table table = createTableExample();

        writeContentInTable(pdfWriter, table, 50, 500);
    }

    public static void writeContentInTable(PdfWriter pdfWriter, Table table, int xPos, int yPos) {
        try {
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
                writeContentInTable(document, table, xPos, yPos);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //Logging Errors
        }
    }

    public static void writeContentInTable(Document document, Table table, int xPos, int yPos) {
        table.setFixedPosition(xPos, yPos, table.getWidth());
        document.add(table);
    }

    private Table createTableExample() {
        Table table = new Table(3);
        Cell cell = new Cell(1, 3)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .add("Cell with colspan 3");
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new Cell(2, 1)
                .add("Cell with rowspan 2")
                .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
        table.addCell(cell);
        table.addCell("Cell 1.1");
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("Cell 1.2"));
        table.addCell(new Cell()
                .add("Cell 2.1")
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
                .setMargin(5));
        table.addCell(new Cell()
                .add("Cell 1.2")
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
                .setPadding(5));
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you've mentioned in Itext 7,"Coordinates specified correspond to bottom left corner and it grows upwards But what about If I want coordinates starts from top left and grows downwards? How should I do that?

Comment: Use `setRelativePosition` method instead of `setFixedPosition` 
See documentation https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.1/com/itextpdf/layout/ElementPropertyContainer.html#setRelativePosition-float-float-float-float-   Example: `setRelativePosition(xPos, yPos, 10, 0);`